# Amazon Web Services/Google Cloud for iOS application

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to setup a database for an iOS app I'm building to be used amongst a lot of users. I've been looking into the services that Google Cloud & AWS offers, and I'm having difficulty figuring out both what services I would need to use exactly, and how much each would cost.

As of now, I just want somewhere to host the data that will eventually be in MySQL databases that I'm going to use for the app.

A quick 101 on how this stuff is supposed to work would be great! Be as explanatory as possible, because I'm totally new to all of this DB stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). One big advantage it provides is unlimited scaling and geo-diversity right out of the box. So you deploy your app and it magically grows and shrinks to accomodate database demand. Re: the database itself, you have two options: [Google Cloud SQL](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/), which is a MySQL database engine in the cloud, or the [App Engine Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/), which is a scalable NoSQL database built into App Engine.

If you require MySQL, e.g. because you've got existing code you need to port, then Cloud SQL would be your best bet, but if you have the flexibility to use a NoSQL database the Datastore is extremely simple and very powerful (like App Engine, it automatically scales from day one). You can also use a new feature called [Google Cloud Endpoints](http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/), to provide a scalable API from your iOS clients to your App Engine app.

Another nice feature of the Google Cloud: if you need to do analysis on your data, you can  use the [App Engine MapReduce API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/dataprocessing/overview), [Google BigQuery](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/), or [Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/drive/start/apps.html#fusiontables).

Comment: That sounds pretty cool. I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 5):

One way to go about this is to use Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk (EBS) service together with their relational database service (RDS) for which you can select MySQL as its RDBMS. You could then write servlets that run on the Elastic Beanstalk to provide a data access layer that can be reached by your iOS app over the internet. Perhaps you will stay within Amazon's Free Tier limits and won't pay anything for an entire year. Good luck.

Comment: That sounds awesome! I'm going to look into that. Any chance I could inquire you further for direction if I run into a wall?

Comment: Of course. I have to say that it is really a great pleasure to work with AWS. Google Cloud may be great as well. I just never tried it.

Comment: How about you post questions for clarifications in this section? Others may be able to join the conversation.